# Migrate RDBMS to Cassandra

Tags: database-design, cassandra, database-migration, rdbms, nosql

I have a RDBMS database with the following tables:

**Airport** ( iata **PK**, airport, city, state, country, lat, long)

**cancellation_cause** ( cod_cancellation **PK**, description)

**Manufaturer** (id_manufacturer **PK**, manufacturer_name)

**Model** (id_model **PK**, model_name, id_manufacturer **FK**)

**Airline**( airline_code **PK**, description)

**airplane_type** (id_AirplaneType **PK**, airplane_type)

**engine_type** (id_engine **PK**, engine_type)

**Aircraft_type** (id_aircraft **PK**, aircraft_type)

**Airplane** (TailNumber **PK**, id_model **FK,** id_aircraft **FK**, airline_code **FK**, id_AirplaneType **FK**, id_engine **FK,** Issue_date, status, year)

**Flight** (id_flight **PK**, cod_cancellation **FK**, TailNumber **FK**, iata_origin **FK**, iata_destin **FK**, Year, Month, DayofMonth, DayofWeek, DepTime, CRSTime, ArrTime, CRSArrTime, FlightNum, AtualElapsedTime, CRSElapsedTime, AirTime, ArrDelay, DepDelay, distance, TaxiIn, TaiOut, Cancelled, Diverted)

***Note: PK - Primary Key; FK - Foreign Key***

I'm conducting a comparative study between RDBMS and Cassandra databases. My goal is to migrate this database to Cassandra and run some queries in both in order to compare the performance of both in a similar case.

Can anyone tell me the best way to do this? How I should model the database in Cassandra?

Comment: Why are you emphasising PK/FK relations? Is that important to you in Cassandra? What are your test cases/benchmarks?

Comment: The PK / FK relationships are related to the relational model. I need to migrate this schema to Cassandra, with the necessary differences. In my test I intend to consult for example the following: airline that registers more departure delays (DepDelay) registered; Airplane type and engine type where there are greater distances covered; What is the manufacturer's model airplane where there is greater flight time? (AirTime). My question is how to relate the data as it is not possible to perform JOIN's.

Comment: -I will elaborate in an answer shortly.

Comment: Thanks. I appreciate your help, I am having many difficulties with this.

Comment: Do tell. I will try to help incrementally and in an answer. Just keep adding to the comments. More I know, more I will be able to refine the answer (I will keep it in an answer to make it more visible and therefore more useful to the broader community)

Comment: For starters, how are you needing to store and how are you reporting this data? Do you need to load the entire database and then incrementally add? If so, what are your increments. What are you need to typically report?

Comment: My data is in csv files. The "flight" file has information about each flight (TailNumber, Flight Number, Date, delays, airport origin and destination, cause cancellation, etc.). This file has millions of records separated by year. The flight information for each year is different files and I have to upload files one at a time. The remaining data is additional data. I have a csv file "airport" with information about the airport. I still have a file "airline" and "airplane". In my relational database the "airplane" file results in several different tables

Comment: The csv file "airplane" contains the fields: TailNumber, Manufacturer, Model, airplane_type, engine_type, aircraft_type, issue_date, status, year. In my relational model this file results in different tables. I think that in Cassandra this is not necessary...

Comment: I added more details. See if this helps.

Comment: Okay, I think I've understood how to model my database in Cassandra and which columns to create.It must create the tables according to the queries to be performed. What I do not understand is how populate a column family with data that are in different csv files. In the relational model that is possible through JOIN's. In Cassandra how do it? It's possible?

Answer (score 5):

Cassandra Query Language (CQL) ver. 3.3 offers semantics for creation of the almost exact replica of the relational tables. This is not the most canonical way to do things, but it can certainly help your situation that, based on comments, seems urgent.

So, using CQL you can create:

```
CREATE TABLE airport( id text PRIMARY KEY, airport text,  
  city text, state text, country text, lat float, long float);
```

then proceed to create other tables like this.

To load csv into a table, use:

```
COPY airport (id, airport, city, state, country, lat, long)  
FROM 'airport.csv' WITH DELIMITER = ';' AND HEADER = TRUE;
```

Not that in Cassandra, you should probably use UUIDs and generate these as your are loading the values.

It looks to me like the airplane can be denormalized, so I would model it all
as one entry, where **airplane** is a super-column, and engine and type are column. With CQL 3.3 you can model this either this way, or the traditional table-creation for each entity way.

See this [post](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/cql3-for-cassandra-experts) for details.

**NOTES:**

Regarding the relationships, you will probably need to abandon the concept of the relationships as you know them that are based on the primary key (PK), foreign key (FK) concepts and related hard constraints. To migrate data over to Cassandra NoSQL you will not be relying on hard links, but on the trust that these entities are linked. The only loss you will experience, just like in moving from strongly-typed to a weakly typed language, will be in the database assured linkages.
You can still have your IDs, you can still maintain ID-based links, but there will be no database enforced integrity contraints. You will be able to perhaps abandon auto-generated IDs. 
Here are some other some very applicable reading materials:

1. [Data modelling best practices](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/ddl/dataModelingApproach.html) from CQL 3.3 manual by Datastax.
2. This [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/279947/Migration-of-Relational-Data-structure-to-Cassandr) describes the practice for migrating the relational schema design and introducing some general design concepts in Cassandra.
3. [Migration best practices](http://www.slideshare.net/planetcassandra/migration-best-practices-from-rdbms-to-cassandra-without-a-hitch) - from RDBMS to NoSQL/Cassandra.
4. The Datastax, a commercial company behind Cassandra has lots of great educational resources and practical advices [here](http://www.datastax.com/relational-database-to-nosql).

Comment: The [CQL 3.3 docs](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/ddl/dataModelingApproach.html) have some good material on data modeling with Cassandra. The tl;dr version is that you should model your tables around your queries, paying particular attention to the partition and clustering keys.