# Data Migration from Mysql to Cassandra

Tags: mysql, database, datastax, datastax-enterprise, database-administration

I need help into below situation.

I have a MySQL table :-

```
CREATE TABLE employees (
    emp_no      INT             NOT NULL,  -- AUTO_INCREMENT??
    birth_date  DATE            NOT NULL,
    first_name  VARCHAR(14)     NOT NULL,
    user_id     INT             NOT NULL,   -- This is primary key of another table.   
    PRIMARY KEY (emp_no));
```

This table have approx 20000 records.

I am transferring this MySQL table to Cassandra table which is as below.

```
CREATE TABLE employees (
    emp_no      uuid,
    birth_date  timestamp,
    first_name  text,
    user_id uuid,
    PRIMARY KEY (emp_no));
```

Now i want to export all 20000 records from MySQL table to Cassandra table.

user_id column is primary key in another table and first_name column is mapped with user_id column also.

Please let me know how can i achieve this .

Below are the details for versions of datastax which I am using. 
**[cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 2.1.15.1403 | DSE 4.8.9 | CQL spec 3.2.1 | Native protocol v3]**

Please suggest me best possible way to data migration from MySQL to Cassandra.

Answer (score 1):

The datastax scenario above is great in your case. An alternative though would be to create a small java project that does that for you. In your case your model from the mysql table to the cassandra table is identical. So you could do the following:

1. Create a java project with hibernate and datastax driver
2. Create a java class for employees
3. Map employees to mysql through hibernate xml mapping (I prefer xml because then I can use the same java model for cassandra)
4. Map employees class to the cassandra table through datastax driver annotations
5. Use hibernate session to bring your employees in batches
6. Use datastax driver to save all the employees in the batch into cassandra.

Your employees class should look like this

```
@Table(keyspace = "your_keyspace", name ="employees")
public class Employee
{
    @PartitionKey(0)
    @Column(name = "emp_no")
    protected UUID employeeNo;

    @Column(name = "birth_date")
    protected Timestamp birthDate;

    @Column(name = "first_name")
    protected String firstName;

    @Column(name = "user_id")
    protected UUID userId;
}
```

Of course Java is not your only option. Datastax driver is available for many languages like C# or python.

Comment: it is not possible if we export mysql table into EXCEL and then load into Cassandra Table. Is it a good idea or not ?
and what will be the possible scenario for failing.

Comment: How do you plan on doing that? I have never tried filling tables this way. Can you give me more details? (Let me also say that the way I describe in the answer above can be reused for future table migrations, so you make it once and have it for whenever you need it)

Comment: convert your mysql table into csv and import into cassandra

Comment: @Ish  yes I tried this but not able to import directly into cassandra 
As per I thought, in mysql table  primary key is "id" which is INT data type and in cassandra table primary key "id" is UUID. So it is getting issue.. and not able to resolve this. really getting hectic due to migration part.

Answer (score 0):

Refer : [Migrate RDBMS to Cassandra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32123310/migrate-rdbms-to-cassandra)

More info: https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/copy_r.html

Please convert your mysql data into CSV and import into cassandra table. This works I have checked this.

Comment: i checked this , but not able to understand in more details. can you provide me a brief scenario with steps then  It will be more helpful.  Thanks